# SoundCloud Desktop App & LibCurl: How to Upload a File?

Tags: c++, file-upload, libcurl, soundcloud

I am having serious difficulty uploading a file to an authenticated user's account on SoundCloud with LibCurl.

I've gotten as far as getting the following error message from a set of JSON-formatted string (thanks to a debug callback through LibCurl); '"error_message": "Couldn't upload that file, sure they're valid soundfiles?""?'.

The files I have been testing with are of the simplest form, created by various DAWs: PCM Wave, mono and stereo, varying lengths but short (several seconds at the most - for fast testing purposes), 44.1 kHz sampling rate and 16-bit depth. Also, I can upload them through the browser on the SoundCloud site, without complaints...

Is anybody able to take a look at the code below to help pinpoint the issue?

```
CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
curl_httppost* formPost = nullptr;
curl_httppost* lastPtr = nullptr;

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "(absolute path)/cacert.pem");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) -1);

headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Expect: 100-continue");
headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Content-type: multipart/form-data");

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "oauth_token",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, /*token*/,
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[asset_data]",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Tone.wav",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[title]",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Tone",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[sharing]",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "public",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "Tone.wav",
              CURLFORM_FILE, "C:/440 Hz Tone - 3 Seconds.wav",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formPost);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) /* size of file in bytes */);

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, (long) 1);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, /*debug function*/);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, (long) 0);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, /*debug progress function*/);

curl_easy_perform (handle);

curl_easy_cleanup (handle);
curl_formfree (formPost);
curl_slist_free_all (headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to this stuff, I didn't understand that the variable "track[asset_data]" is supposed to contain the local file path. Here's the fixed code;

```
CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
curl_httppost* formPost = nullptr;
curl_httppost* lastPtr = nullptr;

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "(absolute path)/cacert.pem");
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) -1);

headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Expect: 100-continue");
headers = curl_slist_append (headers, "Content-type: multipart/form-data");

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "oauth_token",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, /*token*/,
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[title]",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Tone",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[sharing]",
              CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "public",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd (&formPost,
              &lastPtr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "track[asset_data]",
              CURLFORM_FILE, "C:/440 Hz Tone - 3 Seconds.wav",
              CURLFORM_END);

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formPost);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) /* size of file in bytes */);

curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, (long) 1);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, /*debug function*/);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, (long) 0);
curl_easy_setopt (handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, /*debug progress function*/);

curl_easy_perform (handle);

curl_easy_cleanup (handle);
curl_formfree (formPost);
curl_slist_free_all (headers);
```